# How to sum line by line in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sum, python-2.x

I am new at this and couldn't search my exact problem. Though it may be simple to many of you, it is certainly a bowl full of aggravation to me. So, here it is...

I have a text file with columns and rows. The columns are string and the rows are numeric.

```
EXAMPLE: text file. 
Line 1: a.1  2.g  2.2  b.3
Line 2: --------------------
Line 3:  1    2    4    1
Line 4:  3    3    1    1
Line 5:  2    1    5    8
```

I need to read the text file and do some simple math. 
1. sum rows 3,4,5.

The final result should like the following:

```
FINAL 
Line 1: 
Line 2:
Line 3:  8
Line 4:  8
Line 5:  16
```

Here is what i have so far...

```
files = open("exam-grades.txt", "r") 
line_number = 1
for line in files:
    if (line_number == 1 or line_number == 2): 
        continue

    else:

        sum = 0 
        numbers = line.split("\t") 
        for n in numbers:
            sum = sum + float(n) 

        print "Line #: %d / Sum is %d ."%(line_number,sum)

    line_number = line_number + 1
```

Comment: How is what you have written so far deficient?

Comment: Have you tried printing out some of the variables at different points in the loop? Also, note that you are overwriting python's built-in method sum.  Finally, make sure to close your file pointer (files) after you are done

Answer (score 4):

`line_number` is 1 initially, so it hits the first `if` statement and `continue`s without incrementing `line_number`, and thus does the same thing for every line, and doesn't process any of them.

You could correct for this by replacing the top of your loop like so:

```
for line in files:
    if line_number>=3:
        sum = 0
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("exam-grades.txt", "r") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        if i >= 3:
            l = line.split()
            print l[0], l[1], sum((int(i) for i in l[2:] if i.isdigit()))
```

Logic here is pretty simple, you're enumerating lines in a files starting from `1`.
Checking if a line number is `3` or greater, splitting a line into a list and verifying if a list element might be converted to `int`, if it might we summing it up and print out.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to make it bit more flexible - i.e. we won't sum up numbers for lines where at least one value can't be converted to float/number:

```
def to_number(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return None

def sum_in_line(s):
    sm = 0
    cols = s.split()
    try:
        return sum(to_number(x) for x in cols)
    except TypeError:
        return ''

with open("exam-grades.txt", "r") as f:
    i = 1

    for line in f:
        print('%4d:\t%s' % (i, sum_in_line(line)))

        i += 1
```

Input data:

```
a.1  2.g  2.2  b.3
--------------------
 1    2    4    1
 3    3    1    1
 2    1    5    8
 1    a    Z    12
```

Output:

```
   1:
   2:
   3:   8.0
   4:   8.0
   5:   16.0
   6:
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `pass` instead of `continue`, if you use `continue` `line_number` will not be updated

2) to get numbers use `first_part, numbers = line.split(':');numbers = number.split()`.
because if you try to get numbers like you did it will fail:

```
>>> sum = 0
>>> line="Line 3:       1       2       4       1"
>>> numbers = line.split("\t")
>>> numbers
['Line 3:', '1', '2', '4', '1'] 
>>> for n in numbers:
...             sum = sum + float(n) 
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Line 3:
```

You shoud skip the first element `'Line 3:'`.

Try this:

```
files = open("exam-grades.txt", "r") 
line_number = 1
for line in files:
    if (line_number == 1 or line_number == 2 or line_number == 3):
        print "Line %d:" % line_number
        pass

    else:

        sum = 0 
        first_part, numbers = line.split(":")
        for n in numbers.split():
            sum = sum + float(n) 

        print "Line %d: Sum is %d" % (line_number,sum)

    line_number = line_number + 1
```

Comment: @user5874729 Check this.

Comment: thanks!! changed "continue" to "pass."  ....still trying to understand the whole "coding" thing.. anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Seems a bit like a natural for regular expressions to me, depending on the complexity of your numbers...  in this example, I have "data" as a generic iterator for your input data:

```
import re
valid   = re.compile(r'^(?:\s*(\d+\s*))+\s*$')
numbers = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
for line,row in enumerate(data):
    if valid.match(row):
        print "Line #: %d / Sum is %d ."%(line+1,sum(map(int, numbers.findall(row))))
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted - it provides an actual solution to the posed problem.  Would be interested to learn in what way this is not useful in resolving the question...